# Proof of concept for RSA malleability

Tags: rsa, malleability

I'm trying to see how easy RSA malleability is.

I generate 2 ciphertexts with a public key:

```
cat file1 |  openssl rsautl -raw -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem >messageA.encrypted
cat file2 |  openssl rsautl -raw -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem >messageB.encrypted
```

Where file1 and file2 are filled with '1's and '2's resp. I assume `-raw` means no padding schemes. The files are 256 bytes and the keypair is a plain openssl generated RSA keypair of 2048 bits.

Then I read the files per byte and NAND them with a python script:

```
with open("messageA.encrypted", "rb") as f1, open("messageB.encrypted", 'rb') as f2, open("messageC.encrypted", "wb") as fb:
for i in range(256):
    b1 = f1.read(1)
    b2 = f2.read(1)
    out = (~ (b1[0] & b2[0]) & 0xff) # simple '~' is not enough
    outByte = out.to_bytes(1, 'big', signed=False)
    fb.write(outByte)
```

Afterwards I try to decrypt the file, however it fails as follows:

```
openssl rsautl -raw -decrypt -in messageC.encrypted -inkey private.pem 
RSA operation error
139710772687296:error:04065084:rsa routines:rsa_ossl_private_decrypt:data too large for modulus:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ossl.c:411:
```

where file `"messageC.encrypted"` has a size of 256 bytes

Am I wrong to have expected the above to at least to not fail during decryption?

/update, I would have expected the `'O'` (capital 'oh') to be in the decrypted `"messageC.encrypted"`.

Answer (score 3):

NAND is not the appropriate combiner for RSA malleability , and can causes the issue observed by making what's produced larger than the public modulus $N$.

RSA malleability applies to textbook RSA, where encryption goes $$x\to \text{Enc}_{(N,e)}(x)=x^e\bmod N$$ and malleability is the property $$\text{Enc}_{(N,e)}(x_1\cdot x_2\bmod N)=\text{Enc}_{(N,e)}(x_1)\cdot\text{Enc}_{(N,e)}(x_2)\bmod N$$ where $\cdot$ stands for integer multiplication (just nothing to do with NAND).

Verifying this with plaintext consisting of files with bytes containing `1` and `2` requires extracting $N$ from the public key, and large-integer arithmetic modulo $N$.

Comment: hmm I should have looked better at the formulas, of course it fails! However, the 'dot' between $x_1 \cdot x_2$ can still be a `nand` right? Or did I completely misunderstood that part as well?

Comment: @hbogert no multiplication.

Comment: @hbogert No, it is multiplication. You can do it with the C library of openssl, not the command line tool. And then it becomes more of a programming question. It's easier in Python, which has built-in bignums.